# Apply Slide Master changes to a Slide, and then Sever the Connection to the Slide Master

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I need to create a slide that incorporates the existing slide master modifications to the slide directly, and then delete the slide master from the presentation, retaining the changes that the slide master made to the slide.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you need to remove the slide master or the layout that the slide is based on?

Comment: I need to be able to copy/paste the slide to another presentation without being dependent on the slide master.

Comment: It should work if you start with a new presentation based on the blank template, add a new blank slide, then go back to your original slide and in order: 1) copy everything from the slide master and paste it onto the new blank slide, 2) copy everything from the layout the slide's based on and paste that to the new slide, then 3) copy everything from the slide itself and paste it to the new slide. The new slide's content will be independent of any sort of master/layout.  OR copy the slide in sorter view, paste special as PowerPoint Slide onto a new blank slide in the other presentation.